# JavaPackage object is not callable error: Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, python-3.4, apache-zeppelin, py4j

Operations like dataframe.show() , sQLContext.read.json works fine , but most functions gives "JavaPackage object is not callable error" .
eg : when i do

```
dataFrame.withColumn(field_name, monotonically_increasing_id())
```

I get an error

```
File "/tmp/spark-cd423f35-9572-45ee-b159-1b2732afa2a6/userFiles-3a6e1729-95f4-468b-914c-c706369bf2a6/Transformations.py", line 64, in add_id_column
    self.dataFrame = self.dataFrame.withColumn(field_name, monotonically_increasing_id())
  File "/home/himaprasoon/apps/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py", line 347, in monotonically_increasing_id
    return Column(sc._jvm.functions.monotonically_increasing_id())
TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable
```

I am using apache-zeppelin interpreter and have added py4j to python path.

When I do

```
import py4j
print(dir(py4j))
```

the import succeeds

```
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'compat', 'finalizer', 'java_collections', 'java_gateway', 'protocol', 'version']
```

When I tried

```
print(sc._jvm.functions)
```

in pyspark shell it prints

```
<py4j.java_gateway.JavaClass object at 0x7fdaf9727ba8>
```

But when I try this in my interpreter it prints

```
<py4j.java_gateway.JavaPackage object at 0x7f07cc3f77f0>
```

Comment: actually this should also work, but something is off with your conf.

Comment: does your driver and worker have the same python version ?

Comment: Ya. I am working locally and my driver and worker have the same python version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In zeppelin interpreter code

```
java_import(gateway.jvm, "org.apache.spark.sql.*")
```

was not getting executed. Adding this to the import fixed the issue

Comment: Could you clarify where this import should go?