# TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I am getting below error whilie trying to run word count example using sparkstreaming,python.

Not sure how to proceed. Below is the command I am running and the error.

```
  /opt/spark/bin/spark-submit --jars spark-streaming_2.10-2.0.0.jar test_kafka.py broker.txt "localhost:2181:MyTopic"

Error:  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/ubuntu/kafka/libs/test_kafka.py", line 21, in <module>
        kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic], {"metadata.broker.list": brokers})
      File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/streaming/kafka.py", line 122, in createDirectStream
      File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/streaming/kafka.py", line 195, in _get_helper
    TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable
```

Comment: You might have missed some import statements. I had a similar problem with pyspark.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37153866/javapackage-object-is-not-callable-error-pyspark

Answer (score 0):

The error that you get is from the The jar package that you are using. It does not match with your spark/kafka version and it crashes.

I just checked that for the latest as of today spark (2.4.4) and latest kafka 
the following package command works:

```
`--packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.0.2`
```

So try the following command:

`/opt/spark/bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.0.2  test_kafka.py broker.txt "localhost:2181:MyTopic"`

The question is how to choose every time the correct package.
Format of the package should be:

`groupId:artifactId:version`

In the above example:

groupId: is always org.apache.spark

artifactId: grab the latest from spark documentation. in this case I chose: spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11

version:  spark version. Here I chose 2.0.2. It is not the latest, but it has backwards compatibility with spark version 2.4.4 that I am using.